# Is a message in gazebo always a ROS message?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,
I found the Publisher.hh in the code and was wondering, if all messages in Gazebo are ROS messages.

The question came to my mind, because if I want to get an image from a ROS node, it is in the ROS image format and not in the previous Float32. But if I could access the picture without sending it by ROS I could skip the converting step back to openCV.

Thank you for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26451/is-a-message-in-gazebo-always-a-ros-message?/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 64 on 2021-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe you can find your answer [here](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23118/how-does-gazebo-publish-ros-messages/)

---

Originally posted by [morrac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36133/morrac/) with karma: 57 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1